# Pascal's Triangle in VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

I would like to ask if how to do the Pascal's triangle in a textbox (multiline) on VB 6.0. I don't want it to be printed. When the user types the number 5, it should go like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 

1 2 3 4

1 2 3 

1 2 

1
```

My objects are 2 textboxes and a command button
Here's my first code:

```vb
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim MAC As Integer
Dim RIHO As Integer

Text2.Text = ""

MAC = Text1.Text
RIHO = MAC

For MAC = Text1.Text To 1 Step -1
For RIHO = MAC To 1 Step -1
    Text2.Text = Text2.Text & "*"
    Next
    Text2.Text = Text2.Text & vbCrLf
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Lee Burrows I tries using a For-Next statement like so:
'Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim MAC As Integer
Dim RIHO As String
RIHO = ""
MAC = Val(Text1.Text)'.

It just gives me the equivalent value of the given number.
For MAC = Val(Text1.Text) To 1 Step -1
     RIHO = RIHO & "*"
    Text2.Text = RIHO
Next
End Sub'.

Comment: @Steven Doggart My problem is how to generate the triangle that is equivalent to a number, example would be 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no clue how the example could possibly be Pascal's triangle. Furthermore, it is not clear if you are asking for VB code (as in the title) or for VB.Net code (as in the tag).

Anyway, here is a possible solution. You need two nested loops - one for the rows and one for the columns.

```
Dim RIHO As String = ""
Dim MAC = Val(Text1.Text) 'Read user input; you should add error handling
For row As Integer = MAC To 1 Step -1
    For column As Integer = 1 To row
        RIHO = RIHO & column & " " 'add the column number to the output
    Next
    RIHO = RIHO & vbNewLine 'add a new line to the output
Next
Text2.Text = RIHO 'Display the output
```

If you use VB.Net, you should use a more efficient structure for concatenating the strings, e.g. a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Please edit your answer to add the code. It is absolutely unreadable in a comment. What's the result of the new code? How does that differ from your expectations?

Comment: I lack reputations to post my answer but I here's a picture.
[link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LF7QN.png)

Comment: Sorry, I meant "Edit your question". The result looks good to me. Is anything wrong with it?

Comment: No, not at all. But I'll will be editing my question now, thank you for helping.

Comment: Glad I could help. Btw, please mark this answer as the solution (the little check mark to the left) so others can see that the question has been solved.